# Android build is getting failed in mac machine

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-build

cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0
```

global packages:

```
cordova (Cordova CLI) : 7.1.0
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0
Cordova Platforms  : android 6.3.0
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.7.1
```

System:

```
Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1
ios-deploy        : 1.9.0
ios-sim           : 5.0.4
Node              : v6.11.4
npm               : 3.10.10
OS                : macOS Sierra
Xcode             : Xcode 9.0 Build version 9A235
```

Environment Variables:

```
ANDROID_HOME : /Users/mahesh/Library/Android/sdk
```

Misc:

```
backend : pro
```

This is the error i am getting.while building it on mac machine.

```
BUILD FAILED

Total time: 17.969 secs
Error: /Users/mahesh/AppDemo/platforms/android/gradlew: Command failed with exit code 1 Error output:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':_debugApkCopy'.
   > Could not find :SHKit:.
     Required by:
         project :
   > Could not find :SHUIKit:.
     Required by:
         project :`enter code here`
```

Comment: please show your settings.gradle file

Comment: // GENERATED FILE - DO NOT EDIT
include ":"
include ":CordovaLib"

Comment: above line of code in settings.gradle

Comment: Do you have in your workspace a SHKit project?

Comment: no there is no workspace for SHKit project